# Registration php, mysql password, database

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a registration form that will save username and password to database in phpmyadmin.

The problem is that username is saved but the password is not. I mean when I register with password "12345" and when I go to database my password is not saved as "12345", instead it is saved as "96991368fec63c8a1bfc48a70010f84a" or some other random numbers...
In database I put Char(40) for password.

this is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register");

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
session_start();

$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);

    $password =md5($password);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) 
    VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $_SESSION['message'] = " You are now logged in";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("location: Login.php");
}
?>
```

And this is form:

```
form method="post"  action="Registration.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textInput"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" class="textInput"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" class="textInput"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="register"Value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: As `Delete` said, use prepared statements when interacting with your database. They defend against SQL injection. As `zaph` said, you store a hash of the password and verify the hash. PHP has native functions for handling this. Research the different algorithms. And as `Jim Kyle` said, you're storing a hashed password -- DON'T use MD5 for that though. It's notoriously weak and easily cracked.

Answer (score 1):

Do not save the password, save a password hash of the password. When using PHP the simplest approach is to use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

This makes the password secure against attackers and allows easy validation of the password on user login.

More:
When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with an iteration count such that ~100ms or CPU time is consumed. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to the md5 function, on line 12 of your posted code, is converting the user's plaintext entry of the password to the hash string about which you're complaining. Zaph's answer is completely correct; if you store the plaintext password, any intruder has easy access to it -- which is about as insecure as it's possible to be.

In other words, it looks as if your code is doing exactly what you're telling it to do -- even when that's not what you intended or expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statements

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'register';

try {
    $db_conn = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");
    $db_conn->set_charset("utf8");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    session_start();

    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $query = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password)VALUES(?,?,?)");
    $query->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
    $query->execute();
    $counts = $query->num_rows;
    $query->close();

    if ($counts > 0) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = " You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: Login.php"); 
    } else {
        echo 'registration failed... Something went wrong';
    }
}
?>
```

End when user tries to  login do this

```
$query = $db_conn->prepare("select password from users where username = ? limit 1");
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->bind_result($dbpassword);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->fetch();
$query->close();

if (password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) { 
     echo "login success";
} else {
     echo "wrong password";
}
```

Comment: cont: `password_hash` used a unique (random) salt so that two passwords will not hash to the same result. Allowing identical passwords to hash to the same result exposes all accounts that use the same password when one is known of brute forced. See [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.